# Pronunciation of "last night" in American English (Casual Speech)

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

when the question "What did you do last night?" is pronounced, do Americans tend to drop the "t" in the word "last" or is it just a glottal stop? I'm looking for feedback from native speakers. Thank you!

Comment: My experience that this is far too regionally variable around different parts of the US for a sensible rule to be deduced. Some dialects containing sloppy pronunciation is common.

Comment: Brian Tompsett when it comes to you, how do you pronounce it?

Comment: I am native British, but you asked about American English. Although I have been a US resident my dialect is Southern English embraced by Edinburgh, and East Yorkshire tones. I pronounce the "t"s very distinctly; it is my vowels that are more distinctive.

Comment: For me (AmE) the -n- of **night** softens the articulation of the -t- of **last**. The tongue occludes the air outflow by pressing against the ridge behind the top front teeth but then quickly releases to sound the nasal and the vowel of **night**. With **last** the vowel is sounded fairly far back in the throat, so that when the air is occluded the effect is felt in the throat.

Comment: Yep, it's perfectly normal to have no audible /t/ whatsoever.

Comment: Here's a reference someone could use in an answer: https://books.google.com/books?id=9OWQGsOB62UC&pg=PA38  And a helpful site: http://rachelsenglish.com/hurricane-sandy/

Comment: I'm a non-native speaker, but I'd like to remind everyone that the following are not necessarily the same: what the speaker thinks they do, what they really do, what the listener hears, and what they think they hear.

Comment: The answer may be affected by how much alcohol was consumed. Seriously.

Comment: I should add that I'm from Pennsylvania, which is in the north, but have lived in Atlanta, Georgia in the south.  Down South (and in speakers whose accent is southern-influenced) you're much more likely to hear "lass night" with no audible indication whatsoever that there's a dental at the end of **last**, whereas in the north,  even when we slur those words, we do have a little something going on there.

Answer (score 2):

The t is often elided due to the n. I use an alveolar stop to close out the s, and use that contact for the n, and release it for the i. I feel that's somewhat distinguishable from "lass night", as I use a velar stop to end the s instead.

These stops aren't plosives, they just block the airflow and are released without a puff. And also, this is with clear enunciation. I will note that I don't always elide the plosive t in "last night", but I seem to usually do so. And that "lass night" has a bit of a race between the velar and alveolar stops.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an American, I've lived primarily in New York, Ohio, and Michigan, fairly briefly in Missouri and Pennsylvania. Without conducting a careful study, I think almost everyone I've spoken to pronounces it "last nite", i.e. they do pronounce both "t"s, but the "t" in "last" tends to be less clearly enunciated than the "t" in night. (It's hard to describe such subtleties of pronunciation, probably would be better to record it and upload, but I'm not that ambitious this morning.)

Comment: When I saw this question I thought, "Of course I pronounce the /t/", but when I compare how I say "last night" and "last week", the "t" in the first one is definitely significantly elided, if not entirely missing. Still sounds a bit different than if I say "Lass night" (Scottish ladies night, I guess), though.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the *t* in *night* is pronounced in standard American English.  Having lived in several parts of the country, my experience is that pronunciation differences of this phrase are regional or cultural.

Comment: The OP is asking about the /t/ in *last* when it precedes *night* in connected speech.